# Ubuntu server - create group, create user, user specific access

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu server.  How can I create a group lets call that group 'mypeople'  then add a user to 'mypeople' lets use user 'brad'.

and have 'brad' only access to /var/www/brad/.  'brad' can write,read,execute in his directory and have shell access.

Answer (score 93):

**Creating a group**

```
sudo addgroup groupname
```

**Adding an existing user into this group**

```
sudo adduser username groupname
```

**Permissions Restriction**

See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/149404/how-can-i-create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders) for permissions.

Comment: I got a `adduser: The user \`username\` does not exist.` output.

Comment: You need to have the user created before adding to a group. Usee adduser 'username'  first

Comment: Just in case, groupname must be in lowercase

Answer (score 5):

**Creating a group **

we can add the group as below, and also you need to add the group id also.

**eg - group name - fpsalph,group id - 10000**

**groupadd** -g 10000 fpsalpha

after that, you can check it by this command.

tail /etc/group