# To create an user without login access, who only has permission to his home folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a `main_user` that also has a root access to the node. Following [question](https://superuser.com/q/149404/723632) is related to permissions for users who are connected via ssh.

I would like to constrain a user to only have permissions for his/her home folder in linux and *in addition to that without having ssh login access*.

**[Q]** How can I configure such a user?

**My approach:** Is this approach a recommended way to do it? Still guest user has read permission to all directories under `root` (`'/'`) directory such as `/var /bin /tmp /sys /bin /dev /mnt` etc. I am not sure is there any users' important files under those directories.

```
main_user@server$ chmod go-rwx /home/* #I disabled read access of guest user into all users' home directories under /home.
main_user@server$ sudo useradd -d /var/lib/guest -m guest -s /bin/bash
main_user@server$ sudo su - guest # I switch into guest user.
guest@server$ # Here guest user has no write permission to other folders.
```

Comment: Your title might be a little misleading for what you're asking.  The user will still need to login to access his own stuff, otherwise anybody can access that user's stuff.  Is what you're asking how to limit the users access so he can see only his own folder?  Should he be able to execute unprivileged commands or apps available to all other users?  Execute his own apps stored in his folder?  Or do you want this to function simply as a personal file storage container?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I want to create a dummy user that only root-user have access into his stuff and no-one else. My main goal is to submit a slurm-job under that dummy user (https://stackoverflow.com/q/44540590/2402577), so I can prevent dummy user to alter other users’ files. `Execute his own apps stored in his folder` ==> Yes.  
`Personal file storage container` => Yes, his slurm-job’s source code will be stored under his directory. `Should he be able to execute unprivileged commands`=>I want him to have access binary files that are installed into system via root user.  @fixer1234