# Per folder user

Tags: linux

How do I make it like in linux (ubuntu 16.04) that I can create an user and it only has access to the one folder I set it to.

So as example I can have the folder '/home/nicefolder' and I can get the user 'lol123' to only have access to that (and also make it like it does not have read perms in other folders and stuff).

Comment: What is your 'destination' environment?

Comment: To enable normal operation of the system, the user needs to be able to access (read and execute as appropriate) the base system. So I’m not entirely sure what you’re trying to accomplish. Could you perhaps expand? Specifically on what the user should *not* have access to.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered in ["To create an SSH user who only has permission to access specific folders"](https://superuser.com/questions/149404/to-create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders).

Also see the ["Give user read/write access to only one directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101576/give-user-read-write-access-to-only-one-directory) question from the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) from more information.