# Linux Kiosk Mode for Specified Programs

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kiosk, obs-studio

I am using Linux Mint and I want to only be able to run certain apps on it. All the posts that I have found so far are about locking it down to a browser which isn't what I want as I need to be able to run multiple programs. I want to be able to run

1. File Explorer (or whatever it is called on Linux)
2. OBS Studio
3. Media Player

If you know of anything that will help, please let me know
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user with limited permissions, but allowing the user to use Files (AKA nautilus), you open up the possibility to do other things.

An easier thing might be to create a bootable Mint DVD or other read-only media (e.g. an XD flash card with tab set as locked), let the user do as s/he pleases, with no permanent change left after reboot.

Comment: how would you do it so that the user has limited permissions?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/149404/to-create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders